# Replace blank cells with character

Tags: r

I'm working on a data set that looks as follow:

```
191  
282 A

202  
210 B
```

I would like to replace those empty cells at the second column with a character, say 'N'. How can I efficiently do this in R?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An example data frame:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
191 ''
282 A
202 ''
210 B")
```

You can use `sub` to replace the empty strings with `"N"`:

```
dat$V2 <- sub("^$", "N", dat$V2)

#    V1 V2
# 1 191  N
# 2 282  A
# 3 202  N
# 4 210  B
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this solution 10 years later who requires extra context, `sub` uses regex by default, and `"^$"` is a regex that matches the empty string (^ is start of string, $ is end, with nothing in between)

Answer (score 11):

Another way:

Assuming the same data structure as wibeasley has put:

```
ds <- data.frame(ID=c(191, 282, 202, 210), Group=c("", "A", "", "B"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

you can just write:

```
ds$Group[ds$Group==""]<-"N"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data.frame is something like this.

```
ds <- data.frame(ID=c(191, 282, 202, 210), Group=c("", "A", "", "B"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You can check the length of each element, and replace it with "N" if the length is zero.

```
ds$Group <- ifelse(nchar(ds$Group)==0, "N", ds$Group)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFrame$FeatureName[which(DataFrame$FeatureName == "")] <- "N"
```